# In triangle ABC, $m\angle{A}=a\log{x}$ $m\angle{B}=a\log{2x}$ $m\angle{C}=a\log{4x}$. what is $m\angle{B}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> In triangle ABC, $m\angle{A}=a\log{x}$ $m\angle{B}=a\log{2x}$ $m\angle{C}=a\log{4x}$. what is $m\angle{B}$

**My steps**

$a\log{x}+a\log{2x}+\log{4x}=\pi$

which becomes $a\log{x^a}+\log{2x^a}+\log{4x^a}=\pi$

which devolves into: $\log(2^ax^{3a})$

from then I don't know what to do

btw angle B is supposed to be $\frac{\pi}{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
\pi
&=a\log{x}+a\log{2x}+a\log{4x}\\
&=\log{x^a}+\log{(2x)^a}+\log{(4x)^a}\\
&=\log{x^a2^ax^a4^ax^a}\\
&=\log{x^{3a}8^a}\\
&=\log{x^{3a}2^{3a}}\\
&=a\log{x^{3}2^{3}}\\
&=a\log{(2x)^{3}}\\
&=3a\log{2x}\\
&=3m\angle B\\
\end{array}
$

That was my initial proof.

This may be simpler.

$\begin{array}\\
\pi
&=a\log{x}+a\log{2x}+a\log{4x}\\
&=a(\log{x}+\log{4x})+a\log{2x}\\
&=a\log{4x^2}+a\log{2x}\\
&=2a\log{2x}+a\log{2x}\\
&=3a\log{2x}\\
&=3m \angle B\\
\end{array}
$

Nice that they agree.

Comment: The sum of the angles of a triangle is $\pi$, not $2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks. Fortunately easy to fix my silly error. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

$a\log{x}+a\log{2x}+a\log{4x}= \pi$

$=a(\log(8x^3))=a(\log(2x)^3)=3a(\log(2x))$

Therefore, angle $B = a(\log(2x))={\pi\over 3}$